# Using my own service with Laravel4

Tags: service, laravel, laravel-4

In my app, I was testing Google Directions API with ajax, but since I was just testing all the logic was in the `routes.php` file. Now I want to do things the proper way and have three layers: route, controller and service.

So in the routes I tell Laravel which method should be executed:

```
Route::get('/search', 'DirectionsAPIController@search');
```

And the method just returns what the service is supposed to return:

```
class DirectionsAPIController extends BaseController {
    public function search() {
        $directionsSearchService = new DirectionsSearchService();
        return $directionsSearchService->search(Input::all());
    }
}
```

I created the service in `app/libraries/Services/Directions` and called it `DirectionsSearchService.php` and copied all the logic I developed in routes:

```
class DirectionsSearchService {
    public function search($input = array()) {
        $origin = $input['origin'];
        $destination = $input['destination'];
        $mode = $input['mode'];

        // do stuf...

        return $data;
    }
}
```

I read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers) and [some place else](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/199) (and [this](http://three.laravel.com/docs/models) too) and did what I was supposed to do to register a service:

```
class DirectionsAPIController extends BaseController {
    public function search() {
        App::register('libraries\Services\Directions\DirectionsSearchService');
        $directionsSearchService = new DirectionsSearchService();
        return $directionsSearchService->search(Input::all());
    }
}

// app/libraries/Services/Directions/DirectionsSearchService.php
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DirectionsSearchService extends ServiceProvider {
}
```

I also tried adding `libraries\Services\Directions\DirectionsSearchService` to the `providers` array in `app/config/app.php`.

However, I am getting this error:

> HP Fatal error:  Class
>   'libraries\Services\Directions\DirectionsSearchService' not found in
>   /home/user/www/my-app-laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 549

What am I doing wrong? And what is the usual way to use your own services? I don't want to place all the logic in the controller...

Comment: Friendly warning that you are reading up Laravel 3 docs at http://three.laravel.com/docs/models. A lot of things have changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 main things that you are missing:

1. There is a difference between a ServiceProvider and your class. A service provider in Laravel tells Laravel where to go look for the service, but it does not contain the service logic itself. So `DirectionsSearchService` should not be both, imho.
2. You need to register your classes with `composer.json` so that autoloader knows that your class exists.

To keep it simple I'll go with Laravel IoC's [automatic resolution](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution) and not using a service provider for now.

**app/libraries/Services/Directions/DirectionsSearchService.php:**

```
namespace Services\Directions;

class DirectionsSearchService
{
    public function search($input = array())
    {
        // Your search logic
    }
}
```

You might notice that `DirectionsSearchService` does not extend anything. Your service becomes very loosely coupled.

And in your **DirectionsAPIController.php** you do:

```
class DirectionsAPIController extends BaseController
{
    protected $directionsSearchService;

    public function __construct(Services\Directions\DirectionsSearchService $directionsSearchService)
    {
        $this->directionsSearchService = $directionsSearchService;
    }

    public function search()
    {
        return $this->directionsSearchService->search(Input::all());
    }
}
```

With the code above, when Laravel tries to `__construct()` your controller, it will look for `Services\Directions\DirectionsSearchService` and injects into the controller for you automatically. In the constructor, we simply need to set it to an instance variable so your `search()` can use it when needed.

The second thing that you are missing is to register your classes with composer's autoload. Do this by adding to composer.json's autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ... // Laravel's default classmap autoloads
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Services\\": "app/libraries/Services"
    }
}
```

And do a `composer dump-autoload` after making changes to composer.json. And your code should be working again.

---

The suggestion above can also be better with a service provider and coding to the interface. It would make it easier to control what to inject into your controller, and hence easier to create and inject in a mock for testing.

It involves quite a few more steps so I won't mention that here, but you can read more in [Exploring Laravel’s IoC container](http://culttt.com/2014/03/24/exploring-laravels-ioc-container/) and [Laravel 4 Controller Testing](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-controller-testing-48414f4782d0).